# Pick a specific [language], don't tag-spam

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) tag currently has 57 questions and no tag Wiki.

It's *highly* ambiguous what this means. Is this talking about programming languages or spoken languages? Which one?

This tag adds little information to the question, does not mean the same thing in all contexts, and isn't even necessarily on-topic. Can we burninate this before it gets even bigger?

Comment: There could be a use for something related to spoken/written language or linguistics, but those probably are better off with more specific tags anyway. What are some of the questions about w/ this tag? Anything that mind indicate what it is intended for?

Comment: @TylerH Its use is all over the map - some people use it for programming problems related to spoken language (e.g. localizing to specific languages), some people use it for programming language problems (which is probably due to its ambiguity).

Comment: Looking through the list, there's a lot of confusion with "locale" (language choosers, specific languages in text, etc.)

Comment: Suggested title: Please watch your [language]

Comment: @HereticMonkey Or [character-encoding] (which seems to be quite a few)

Comment: "Language" is a real thing when used in combination with [tag:context-free-grammar] – but the connection is so strong it probably does not need [tag:language]. And also not yet another tag [tag:context-free-grammar-language].